# How to search an element of an array?

Tags: c++

My arrray looks like 
int myarray[]={6,5,2,6,7,8,6};
I want my program to say 
if a user enters '6'
"your number is found 3 times at 0,3,6".
And if its not found say"not found".

Here is my effort:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool flag=false;
  int x[]={9,11,6,7,6,4,6};
  int count=0;
  int n,i,j,c;
  cout<<"What number do you want to search : ";
  cin >>n;
  for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    if(x[i]==n){ 
      count++; 
      flag=true; 
    } 
  } 
  if(flag){ 
    cout <<n<<" is found "<<count<<" times in :"; 
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){ 
      if(x[i]==n) cout <<i<<','; 
     } 
   } else { 
     cout <<n<<" is not found"<<endl; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Take it step by step. Can you check if the first element is a 6? If so display "found 1 time at 0". Can you then check the second element? And then generalize?

Comment: No offense to the OP, but why would this be upvoted? It's a basic question, which one can solve after reading a few chapters in a decent book, and no effort was shown.

Comment: Tnxs guys i figured it

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool flag=false;
    int x[]={9,11,6,7,6,4,6};
    int count=0;
    int n,i,j,c;
    cout<<"What number do you want to search : ";
    cin >>n;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(x[i]==n){
            count++;
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    if(flag){
        cout <<n<<" is found "<<count<<" times in :";
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            if(x[i]==n)
            cout <<i<<',';
        }
    }
    else{
        cout <<n<<" is not found"<<endl;
    }
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a starting example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    int myarray[7] = {6,5,2,6,7,8,6};
    int value;
    cin >> value;
    bool not_found = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        if(myarray[i] == value) {
            cout << "Found value " << value << " at position " << i << "\n";
            not_found = false;
        }
    }
    if(not_found)
        cout << "Not found\n";
    return 0;
}
```

which, when the user inputs 6, will output:

```
Found value 6 at position 0
Found value 6 at position 3
Found value 6 at position 6
```

If you want to match the exact same output as the one in your question, you could store the indices (all the `i`s in an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for example), and then print them.

Answer (score -2):

this is the code to search element in array .this method is linear search

```
int main()
{
int myarray[100]={6,5,2,6,7,8,6};
int sch,i,count;
int flag=1;
count=sizeof( myarray )/sizeof( myarray[0] );
cout<<"enter element to search";
cin>>sch;
for(i=0;i<count;i++)
{
   if(myarray[i]==sch){
      cout<<"element"<<sch<<"found. it is in position of"<<i+1;
      int flag=0;
   }

}
if(flag==1)
  cout<<"not found";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: may i know why i got down voted?

Comment: `void main`? Stopped reading. Didn’t downvote.

Comment: "void main? Stopped reading" i didn't get meaning

Comment: You didn’t get meaning but changed to int? And inserted useless return 0?